# Angular2 push card animation?

Tags: css, angular, animation, typescript

I want the top side of the `card` animate like the bottom side.

Make it full screen When click the `card` and push the neighbor `card` away.

How can i do this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   animations: [
     trigger('heroState', [
       state('inactive', style({ height: '*', width: '*' })),
       state('active',  style({ position: 'absolute', top: '0', margin: '0',  padding: '0', width: '100%', height: '100%' })),
       transition('inactive <=> active', animate('5000ms ease-in-out'))
     ])
   ],
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/uqqYXCc1ZGv5SMtBcCM5?p=preview

Comment: Here a tip on how to post example code [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this will help you get an answer sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends, if you want to push it away, you cannot position anything absolute, or you will have to do a lot of calculating.

This Code Pushes the bottom card way, but the height is fixed on `500px`. You could tweak/change this. To `height:'100%'` or so.

```
animations: [
     trigger('heroState', [
       state('inactive', style({ height: '*', width: '*' })),
       state('active',  style({ height: '500px' })),
       transition('inactive <=> active', animate('500ms ease-in-out'))
     ])
   ]
```

**Update:**
Here I added a small update to your plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/YkPSXgFIEKQefbkYkZIh?p=preview
it pushes the boxes away, and if activated it closes other open Cards.

**Update 2:**
If your really want, the top card being pushed away, you would need something like jQuery or so, since it affects the parent element, what cannot be change with regular css.
Here an example. *You would have to tweak it to your needs.*
*(And a present it works only for 3 cards, and the code should be "optimized")*

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
            container.addEventListener("click", event => {
                let selecteClass = "selected";
                if (event.target.className.indexOf("box") > -1) {
                    event.target.className += " clicked";
                    if (event.target.className.indexOf(selecteClass) > -1) {
                        event.target.className = event.target.className.replace(" "+ selecteClass, "");
                        $(".container")[0].className =  $(".container")[0].className.replace(/ margin-4-[^"]+/,"");
                    } else {
                        let currentSelection = document.querySelector(".box." + selecteClass);
                        if (currentSelection) {
                            currentSelection.className = currentSelection.className.replace(" "+ selecteClass, "");
                        }
                        event.target.className += " " + selecteClass;
              
                    }
                    $(".container:has(.box:first-child.selected)").addClass("margin-4-first");
                    $(".container:has(.box:nth-child(2).selected)").addClass("margin-4-second");
                    $(".container:has(.box:nth-child(3).selected)").addClass("margin-4-third");
                }
            });

            container.addEventListener("transitionend", event => {
                if (event.propertyName === "background-color") {
                    event.target.className = event.target.className.replace(" clicked", "");
                }
            });
```

```css
html{
                height: 100%;
            }

            body{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            
            .container {
                background-color: #EEEEEE;
                height: 100%;
                padding: 20px 0 0 0;
                margin-top:0;
                overflow: hidden;
                transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
            }
            
            .box {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                width: 300px;
                height: 50px;
                margin: 20px auto 10px auto;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px #828282;
                transition: height 0.5s ease-out, background-color 0.05s ease-out;
            }
            
            .selected {
                height: 90%;
            }
            
            .clicked {
                background-color: #eeeeee;
            }

            .margin-4-first{
                margin-top:0;
            }

            .margin-4-second{
                margin-top: -100px;
                padding-bottom:20%;
            }

            .margin-4-third{
                margin-top:-150px;
                padding-bottom:20%;
            }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Boxes</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fiex the `height` not a good solution. The top side of the `card` is not move and the bottom side may out of screen.

Comment: @user6148078 did you checkout the plnkr link? here you can tweak the height, as mention put in percentages, or em's or ... . I set the fixed with just for testing.

Comment: @user6148078 by the way should it work as the image or as your plnkr? because my solution works as the image, except for the pusing of the top card, but this is not easy possible with angular animation.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. Yes the difficulty is to pushing the top card. I try to use `position: 'absolute', top: '0'`, but it not look like the image.

Comment: check my added code, I hope it works as a rough guide. It needs some tweaks, but pushes the top card.